# why does InnoDB keep on growing without for every update?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table which consists of heavy blobs, and I wanted to conduct some tests on it.

I know deleted space is not reclaimed by innodb, so I decided to reuse existing records by updating its own values instead of createing new records.

But I noticed, whether I delete and insert a new entry, or I do UPDATE on existing ROW, InnoDB keeps on growing.

Assuming I have 100 Rows, each Storing 500KB of information, My InnoDB size is 10MB, now when I call UPDATE on all rows (no insert/ no delete), the innodb grows by ~8MB for every run I do. All I am doing is I am storing exactly 500KB of data in each row, with little modification, and size of blob is fixed.

What can I do to prevent this?

I know about optimize table, but I cant do it because on regular usage, the table is going to be 60-100GB big, and running optimize will just stall entire server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I noticed, whether I delete and insert a new entry, or I do UPDATE on existing ROW, InnoDB keeps on growing.

`InnoDB` is a multiversion system.

This means that each time you update or delete a row, the previous version of the row gets copied to a special place called a `rollback segment`. The original record is rewritten with the new data (in case of an `UPDATE`) or marked as deleted (in case of a `DELETE`).

If you do a transaction rollback or execute a concurrent `SELECT` statement (which has to see the previous version since the new one is not yet committed), the data is retrieved from the `rollback segment`.

The problem with this is that `InnoDB` tablespace *never shrinks*. If the tablespace is full, new space is allocated. The space occupied by the rollback information from the commited transactions may be reused too, but if the tablespace is full it will be extended and this is permanent.

There is no supported way to shrink the `ibdata*` files except backing up the whole database, dropping and recreating the `InnoDB` files and restoring from the backup.

Even if you use `innodb_file_per_table` option, the rollback tablespace is still stored in the shared `ibdata*` files.

Note, though, that space occupied by the tables and space occupied by the tablespace are the different things. Tables can be shrunk by running `OPTIMIZE` and this will make them more compact (within the tablespace), but the tablespace itself cannot be shrunk.

Comment: Thanks for in depth explanation, I have to find some laternative way to store huge data if data will be modified, Is there some easy way to reclaim deleted rows if possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce table size by running Optimize query

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name;
```

more information can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)

Comment: I know about optimize table, but I cant do it because on regular usage, the table is going to be 60-100GB big, and running optimize will just stall entire server. and on InnoDB, Optimize is mapped to ALTER TABLE, which is kind of rebuilding the table.

Comment: I'm afraid it is only one solution to do that, unless you planing to mirror database servers.